# JSON parse error for integer starting with leading + sign e.g. +12345

Tags: json, object, parsing, parseint

JSON request payload :-

```
{
    "time": +12345
}
```

A JSONParseException is thrown:-

> "$errorDump":
>   "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException:Unexpected character
>   ('1' (code 49)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus
>   sign

As per validating the datatype, `time` cannot be sent as String. It has to be int only.
Then how numbers such as +12345 are allowed for input field `time`?

Comment: It should be like -  {"time": "+12345"}

Comment: Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[' - You probably have an extra comma at the end of your list. Something like: ["a", "b", ]
see common errors - https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: So String value is the only option here, though the input field "time" is allowed to have only numeric value. Anyways, thanks Mumtaz for replying.